# Explanation of heterogeneity

Tags: meta-analysis, heterogeneity

Following is the output of meta-analysis of five fictitious studies:

```
      OR           95%-CI %W(fixed) %W(random)
1 0.7037 [0.3963; 1.2495]      2.15      10.29
2 0.6047 [0.5166; 0.7079]     29.95      24.79
3 0.9097 [0.8001; 1.0343]     38.59      25.78
4 0.9696 [0.8285; 1.1348]     25.02      24.80
5 0.5872 [0.3831; 0.9000]      4.30      14.34

Number of studies combined: k=5

                         OR           95%-CI       z  p.value
Fixed effect model   0.8151 [0.7513; 0.8842] -4.9196 < 0.0001
Random effects model 0.7639 [0.6060; 0.9631] -2.2785   0.0227

Quantifying heterogeneity:
tau^2 = 0.0499; H = 2.44 [1.62; 3.68]; I^2 = 83.2% [61.8%; 92.6%]

Test of heterogeneity:
     Q d.f.  p.value
 23.81    4 < 0.0001

Details on meta-analytical method:
- Mantel-Haenszel method
- DerSimonian-Laird estimator for tau^2
```

How can you explain in layman terms what is heterogeneity and how above output is interpreted in terms of heterogeneity? What are acceptable values of $I^2$ and $\tau^2$? What is the meaning of p value <0.05 here?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This Q&A may be helpful https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193168/reporting-of-heterogeneity-in-metaanalysis?rq=1